# Dictionary key count has wrong result

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, foreach

I'm working with Swift 4 for macOS and I have a problem with my for each loop.

My code:

```
var dict = [String:Int]()

for x in 0 ..< 5 {
    if !dict.keys.contains("\(x)") {
        print("NEW KEY: \(x)")
        dict = ["\(x)" : x]
    }
}

print(dict.keys.count)
```

My print results:

```
NEW KEY: 0
NEW KEY: 1
NEW KEY: 2
NEW KEY: 3
NEW KEY: 4
1
```

But why is `keys.count = 1`?

Comment: Learn to debug! Put a break on `dict = ["\(x)" : x]`. Step and check the value of `dict` at each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **overwriting the dictionar**y with each iteration of the `for` loop.

Replace

```
dict = ["\(x)" : x]
```

with

```
dict["\(x)"] = x
```

Comment: @Ghost108 If the answer was correct, then accept it (click the checkmark at the left so that it is green). It help others.